How can anonymous users interact with Vue3 frontend, using GraphQL and Django backend?
While building a blog app, I want to create a user interaction such as like, dislike and share. However, I want the users to be anonymous (not authenticated). How can I achieve this to display counts for like, dislike and share in Vue 3 JS? I want to fetch the interactions from the backend, as the app mounts (onMounted) lifescycle hook. But when I refresh the page it displays the initial values like(0), dislike (0) and share(0).
SocialMediaButtons.vue:
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="likePost" :disabled="isLiked">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="thumbs-up" style="color: green; font-size: 24px; margin-right: 50px;" /> Like ({{ interactions.like }})
    </button>
    <button @click="dislikePost" :disabled="isDisliked">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="thumbs-down" style="color: red; font-size: 24px; margin-right: 50px;" /> Dislike ({{ interactions.dislike }})
    </button>
    <button @click="sharePost" :disabled="isShared">
      <font-awesome-icon icon="fa-solid fa-share" style="color: #0077B5; font-size: 24px; margin-right: 50px;" /> Share ({{ interactions.share }})
    </button>

    <div class="social-media-icons" style="display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center; height: 10vh;">
      Share this post on:
      <button @click="shareOnFacebook">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="facebookIcon" class="fa-2x icon-facebook" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
      </button>
      <button @click="shareOnLinkedIn">
        <font-awesome-icon :icon="['fab', 'linkedin']" class="fa-2x icon-linkedin" style="margin-right: 50px;" />
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, computed, watch, onMounted } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
import { useQuery } from '@vue/apollo-composable';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/vue-fontawesome';
import { faThumbsUp, faThumbsDown, faShareSquare } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';
import { faFacebookSquare, faLinkedin } from '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons';
import { defineProps } from 'vue';
import { useInteractionStore } from '@/stores/interactionStore';
import { GET_POST_BY_SLUG} from '@/graphql/queries/postQuery';

const props = defineProps({
  postId: String, // Define the type of `postId` prop if necessary
});

const facebookIcon = ref(faFacebookSquare);
const linkedinIcon = ref(faLinkedin);

// Construct the post URL
const shareUrl = computed(() => `${window.location.origin}/post/${props.postId}`);

const shareOnLinkedIn = () => {
  console.log('Sharing on LinkedIn:', shareUrl.value);
  window.open(`https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=${encodeURIComponent(shareUrl.value)}`, '_blank');
};

const shareOnFacebook = () => {
  console.log('Sharing on Facebook:', shareUrl.value);
  window.open(`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=${encodeURIComponent(shareUrl.value)}`, '_blank');
};

const post = ref(null);
const route = useRoute();
const slug = ref(route.params.slug);

const { result, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_POST_BY_SLUG, { slug: slug.value });

console.log('Initial useQuery state:', {
  result: result.value,
  loading: loading.value,
  error: error.value,
});

const interactionStore = useInteractionStore();

/// Local state to keep track of interactions
const interactions = ref({ like: 0, dislike: 0, share: 0 });

const updateLocalInteractions = () => {
  interactions.value = { ...interactionStore.interactions };
};

// Fetch initial interactions when component mounts
onMounted(async () => {
  await interactionStore.fetchInteractions(props.postId);
  updateLocalInteractions();
});

// Watch for changes in the interactionStore.interactions and update local interactions
watch(
  () => interactionStore.interactions,
  (newInteractions) => {
    interactions.value = { ...newInteractions };
  }
);

// Functions to handle interactions
const getLocalStorageKey = (action) => `post_${props.postId}_${action}`;

const isLiked = ref(localStorage.getItem(getLocalStorageKey('like')) === 'true');
const isDisliked = ref(localStorage.getItem(getLocalStorageKey('dislike')) === 'true');
const isShared = ref(localStorage.getItem(getLocalStorageKey('share')) === 'true');

const updateLocalStorage = (action) => {
  localStorage.setItem(getLocalStorageKey('like'), action === 'like' ? 'true' : 'false');
  localStorage.setItem(getLocalStorageKey('dislike'), action === 'dislike' ? 'true' : 'false');
  localStorage.setItem(getLocalStorageKey('share'), action === 'share' ? 'true' : 'false');
  
  isLiked.value = action === 'like';
  isDisliked.value = action === 'dislike';
  isShared.value = action === 'share';
};

const likePost = async () => {
  try {
    await interactionStore.updateInteraction(props.postId, 'like');
    updateLocalInteractions();
    updateLocalStorage('like');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating like:', error);
  }
};

const dislikePost = async () => {
  try {
    await interactionStore.updateInteraction(props.postId, 'dislike');
    updateLocalInteractions();
    updateLocalStorage('dislike');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating dislike:', error);
  }
};

const sharePost = async () => {
  try {
    await interactionStore.updateInteraction(props.postId, 'share');
    updateLocalInteractions();
    updateLocalStorage('share');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error updating share:', error);
  }
};
</script>

Mutations.py:
# mutations.py

import graphene
from graphene import ObjectType
from . import models



class InteractionsType(graphene.ObjectType):
    like = graphene.Int()
    dislike = graphene.Int()
    share = graphene.Int()

class UpdateInteractions(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        id = graphene.ID(required=True)
        action = graphene.String(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()
    message = graphene.String()
    interactions = graphene.Field(InteractionsType)

    def mutate(self, info, id, action):
        try:
            post = models.Post.objects.get(id=id)
        except models.Post.DoesNotExist:
            return UpdateInteractions(success=False, message="Post not found")

        user_interactions, created = models.Interaction.objects.get_or_create(post=post)

        if action == "like":
            user_interactions.like = user_interactions.like + 1
        elif action == "dislike":
            user_interactions.dislike = user_interactions.dislike + 1
        elif action == "share":
            user_interactions.share = user_interactions.share + 1
        else:
            return UpdateInteractions(success=False, message="Invalid action")

        user_interactions.save()

        return UpdateInteractions(
            success=True,
            message="Interactions updated successfully",
            interactions=user_interactions
        )

class Mutation(ObjectType):
    update_interactions = UpdateInteractions.Field()

interactionStore.js
// interactionStore.js
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import apolloClient from '@/apolloClient';
import { UPDATE_INTERACTIONS } from '../graphql/mutations/postMutation';
import { FETCH_INTERACTIONS } from '../graphql/queries/postQuery';

export const useInteractionStore = defineStore('interactionStore', {
  state: () => ({
    interactions: {
      like: 0,
      dislike: 0,
      share: 0,
    },
  }),
  actions: {
    async fetchInteractions(postId) {
      try {
        const response = await apolloClient.query({
          query: FETCH_INTERACTIONS,
          variables: {
            id: postId,
          },
        });

        // Check if the response data exists and contains the interactions
        if (response.data && response.data.interactions) {
          this.interactions = response.data.interactions;
        } else {
          console.error('Query failed: Response does not contain interactions', response.errors);
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred during query:', error);
      }
    },
    async updateInteraction(postId, action) {
      try {
        const response = await apolloClient.mutate({
          mutation: UPDATE_INTERACTIONS,
          variables: {
            id: postId,
            action,
          },
        });

        if (response.data.updateInteractions.success) {
          this.interactions = response.data.updateInteractions.interactions;
        } else {
          console.error('Mutation failed:', response.data.updateInteractions.message);
          throw new Error('Failed to update interactions');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('An error occurred during mutation:', error);
        throw new Error('Failed to update interactions');
      }
    },     
  },
});

fetch_interactions
export const FETCH_INTERACTIONS = gql`
  query GetInteractions($id: ID!) {
    postById(id: $id) {
      interactions {
        like
        dislike
        share
      }
    }
  }
`;

